# On button focus tabindex jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have included given code

```
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test1" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test2" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test3" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test4" tabindex="4">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test5" id = 'mytest' tabindex="5">
<button tabindex="6" id="add" class="button">Add</button>
```

Now I want when I click on add button then automatically tabindex focus on 
`<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test5" id = 'mytest'  tabindex="5">`. Something to be written on this click function . Please guide me how to solve this.

```
$('#add').click(function(){
  var tab = $('#mytest').attr('tabindex')
  ........
})
```

Comment: So you want to add an input with the correct tabindex and you want to increase the tabindex on the button?

Comment: i don't get it, why do you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
  $('input[tabindex=5]').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test1" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test2" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test3" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test4" tabindex="4">
<input type="text" name="test" placeholder="test5" tabindex="5">
<button tabindex="6" id="add" class="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: Hii will u please guide me if I  do` $('#add').click(function(){
  var tab = $('#mytest').attr('tabindex')
  $('input[tabindex=tab]').focus();
})` then why its not working

Comment: @dinshawraje it would be like $('input[tabindex="tab"]').focus(); }) just only because **the value of attribute must be in quotation**
 and if tab is the variable then you must do like $('input[tabindex='" + tab +"' ]').focus(); }) just try and update if it's work or not